# How do I pop the view controller underneath a pushed view controller?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ipod

I want to push a view controller onto the stack, then pop the first one that pushed the new one.

```
-(void) someMethod {
    MegaSuperAwesomeViewController *tempVC = [[MegaSuperAwesomeViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tempVC animated:YES];
    [tempVC release];

    // pop this VC, how?
}
```

EDIT: turns out I can pop back 2 view controllers instead once finished with the new VC.  Still not what I wanted exactly, but it works.  The downside is I need to set a flag to indicate that the covered view is completed.

Comment: Why would you wan't to do this?

Comment: Requirement for the app.  Alternatively I could pop the current view controller, then push the next one, but the current one would be released before completing the push.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a technique of popping back two view controllers, which has a similar problem of yours of the current view controller and its navigationController property going away as soon as you do the first pop:

```
// pop back 2 controllers on the stack to the setup screen
//

// locally store the navigation controller since
// self.navigationController will be nil once we are popped
//
UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

// retain ourselves so that the controller will still exist once it's popped off
//
[[self retain] autorelease];

// Pop back 2 controllers to the setup screen
//
[navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

alternatively, you can directly "party" on the navigation controllers stack of view controllers:

> setViewControllers:animated: Replaces
>   the view controllers currently managed
>   by the navigation controller with the
>   specified items.
>
> - (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated Parameters
>     viewControllers The view controllers
>     to place in the stack. The
>     front-to-back order of the controllers
>     in this array represents the new
>     bottom-to-top order of the controllers
>     in the navigation stack. Thus, the
>     last item added to the array becomes
>     the top item of the navigation stack.
>     animated If YES, animate the pushing
>     or popping of the top view controller.
>     If NO, replace the view controllers
>     without any animations. Discussion You
>     can use this method to update or
>     replace the current view controller
>     stack without pushing or popping each
>     controller explicitly. In addition,
>     this method lets you update the set of
>     controllers without animating the
>     changes, which might be appropriate at
>     launch time when you want to return
>     the navigation controller to a
>     previous state.
>
> If animations are enabled, this method
>   decides which type of transition to
>   perform based on whether the last item
>   in the items array is already in the
>   navigation stack. If the view
>   controller is currently in the stack,
>   but is not the topmost item, this
>   method uses a pop transition; if it is
>   the topmost item, no transition is
>   performed. If the view controller is
>   not on the stack, this method uses a
>   push transition. Only one transition
>   is performed, but when that transition
>   finishes, the entire contents of the
>   stack are replaced with the new view
>   controllers. For example, if
>   controllers A, B, and C are on the
>   stack and you set controllers D, A,
>   and B, this method uses a pop
>   transition and the resulting stack
>   contains the controllers D, A, and B.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 3.0 and
>   later. Declared In
>   UINavigationController.h

So, to "disappear" the view controller directly under you on the navigation stack, in your view controller's viewDidLoad, you could do this:

```
NSMutableArray *VCs = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[VCs removeObjectAtIndex:[VCs count] - 2];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = VCs;
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but the nav array is incompatible with the VCs array you describe, because it has to be mutable.  however, it's not really needed because I can pop back two VC from the new one when finished.  Don't know why I didn't spot it.

Comment: Just added in a "Mutable" in an edit -- small misnake, the technique works though.

Comment: it's not compatible, so I guess I'd have to make a new array, remove the vc, then place the array back?  I wonder if that would cause problems...

Comment: OK.  I didn't vet the code in a real build, but you've got the idea: grab the viewControllers array, edit it, and set it back.  No problems, the api specifically allows you to set a new array of view controllers, see "setViewControllers" in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I had trouble figuring this out also so I wanted to share how I got this to work.

Let's say you have a stack of VCs **VC1** being the root then you push **VC2** and from **VC2** you want to push **VC3** but once pushed you don't want the user to go back to **VC2** but rather to **VC1** (the root). The way to do that is:

```
//push VC3 from VC2
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:VC3 animated:YES];

// now remove VC2 from the view controllers array so we will jump straight back to VC1
NSMutableArray *viewHeirarchy =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.navigationController viewControllers]];
[viewHeirarchy removeObject:self];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = viewHeirarchy;
```

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Other methods left the old view controller's navigation items in the stack. This is the only one that works properly for me now that iOS 7 introduces popGestures. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, this worked for me too. Initially I was trying to do this after VC2 had pushed VC3 (in UINavigationController's delegate method) which works in iOS8, but in iOS7 doing it directly after pushing is needed to make the navigation items correctly pop. It also means simpler code!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bogatyr about the tip on 'party on the viewcontroller array for the navcontroller'. I just replaced the entire stack with the one viewcontroller I want to change to, and then log out all the viewcontrollers in the stack to make sure its the only one! Worked great - thanks!

```
    RatingsTableViewController *newViewController = [[RatingsTableViewController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray * newVCarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:newViewController, nil];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = newVCarray;

    [newViewController release];

     NSMutableArray *allControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];

    for (id object in allControllers) {

          NSLog(@"name VC: %@", object);
    }
    [allControllers release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)popToSelf{

    NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.count ; i++) {
        UIViewController *currentVC = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([currentVC isKindOfClass:[YourViewControllerClass class]]) {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:i] animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this recently in Swift using the below code.

```
private func removePushedLoadingViewFromNavHeirarchy() {
    let viewHeirarchyWithoutLoadingView = rootNavigationController
        .viewControllers
        .filter { $0 as? FullScreenLoadingViewController == nil }
    rootNavigationController.viewControllers = viewHeirarchyWithoutLoadingView
}
```

I call this after pushing another view controller like so

```
let viewController = ReviewViewController()
rootNavigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
removePushedLoadingViewFromNavHeirarchy()
```