# Remove viewController AND navigationItem from stack

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationController and I in the current top-of-stack controller, I want to push a new controller on and then remove the current VC.  In short, the goes from

```
[ViewController A]
[ViewController B]
```

to

```
[ViewController A]
[ViewController B]
[ViewController C]
```

to

```
[ViewController A]
[ViewController C]
```

I accomplish this in VC B by:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VCC animated:YES];
[self removeFromParentViewController];
```

Works fine EXCEPT that the navigationItem stack still has the title/backButton from VC B sandwiched between A and C.

How can I remove a VC from the UINavigationController stack AND ALSO update the navigationItem stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Navigation item did not show up because of the "style" of placing/removing the viewcontroller.

Instead of `[self removeFromParentViewController]` use `[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO]` twice first before pushing the newviewcontroller onto the navigationcontroller

Another way is:

```
NSMutableArray *VCs = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[VCs removeObjectAtIndex:[VCs count] - 2];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = VCs;
```

Have a look at this: [How do I pop the view controller underneath a pushed view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985816/how-do-i-pop-the-view-controller-underneath-a-pushed-view-controller)

Give it a try.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  The two-pops-and-a-push method doesn't work; both pops happen but the push never does.  The NSMutableArray method "works" in that the VCs and the navBar are in sync, but the app complains "Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted."  Good news is that it doesn't get _seem_ to get corrupted so I think I can live with this!